# Warping an image using roll, pitch, and yaw

Tags: python, image, opencv, matrix, pitch

I am currently using OpenCV in Python to correct for image distortion in an aerial image.  I have the data for the roll, pitch, and yaw.  I understand that I need to create a warp matrix, and apply the matrix to my original coordinate points to create the output points for the image.  I am able to affect the way the image moves, but I feel that there is an error because the only values that seem to work for very small values.

Here is my current code:

```
warp_mat = np.array([[math.cos(theta)*math.cos(psy), math.cos(phi)*math.sin(psy)+math.sin(phi)*math.sin(theta)*math.cos(psy), math.sin(phi)*math.sin(psy)-math.cos(phi)*math.sin(theta)*math.cos(psy)],\
                    [-1*math.cos(theta)*math.sin(psy), math.cos(phi)*math.cos(psy)-math.sin(phi)*math.sin(theta)*math.sin(psy), math.sin(phi)*math.cos(psy)+math.cos(phi)*math.sin(theta)*math.sin(psy)],\
                    [math.sin(theta), -1*math.sin(phi)*math.cos(theta), math.cos(phi)*math.cos(theta)]], dtype='float32')


srcPts = np.array([[-2064, 1161, 1],\
                  [2064, 1161, 1],\
                  [2064, -1161, 1],\
                  [-2064, -1161, 1]], dtype='float32')

dstPts = np.empty(shape = (4,3), dtype='float32')


dstPts[0][0] = srcPts[0][0] * warp_mat[0][0] + srcPts[0][1] * warp_mat[1][0] + srcPts[0][2] * warp_mat[2][0];
dstPts[0][1] = srcPts[0][0] * warp_mat[0][1] + srcPts[0][1] * warp_mat[1][1] + srcPts[0][2] * warp_mat[2][1];
dstPts[0][2] = srcPts[0][0] * warp_mat[0][2] + srcPts[0][1] * warp_mat[1][2] + srcPts[0][2] * warp_mat[2][2];

dstPts[1][0] = srcPts[1][0] * warp_mat[0][0] + srcPts[1][1] * warp_mat[1][0] + srcPts[1][2] * warp_mat[2][0];
dstPts[1][1] = srcPts[1][0] * warp_mat[0][1] + srcPts[1][1] * warp_mat[1][1] +     srcPts[1][2] * warp_mat[2][1];
dstPts[1][2] = srcPts[1][0] * warp_mat[0][2] + srcPts[1][1] * warp_mat[1][2] + srcPts[1][2] * warp_mat[2][2];

dstPts[2][0] = srcPts[2][0] * warp_mat[0][0] + srcPts[2][1] * warp_mat[1][0] + srcPts[2][2] * warp_mat[2][0];
dstPts[2][1] = srcPts[2][0] * warp_mat[0][1] + srcPts[2][1] * warp_mat[1][1] + srcPts[2][2] * warp_mat[2][1];
dstPts[2][2] = srcPts[2][0] * warp_mat[0][2] + srcPts[2][1] * warp_mat[1][2] + srcPts[2][2] * warp_mat[2][2];

dstPts[3][0] = srcPts[3][0] * warp_mat[0][0] + srcPts[3][1] * warp_mat[1][0] + srcPts[3][2] * warp_mat[2][0];
dstPts[3][1] = srcPts[3][0] * warp_mat[0][1] + srcPts[3][1] * warp_mat[1][1] + srcPts[3][2] * warp_mat[2][1];
dstPts[3][2] = srcPts[3][0] * warp_mat[0][2] + srcPts[3][1] * warp_mat[1][2] + srcPts[3][2] * warp_mat[2][2];


dstPts[0][0] = dstPts[0][0] / dstPts[0][2];
dstPts[0][1] = dstPts[0][1] / dstPts[0][2];
dstPts[0][2] = dstPts[0][2] / dstPts[0][2];

dstPts[1][0] = dstPts[1][0] / dstPts[1][2];
dstPts[1][1] = dstPts[1][1] / dstPts[1][2];
dstPts[1][2] = dstPts[1][2] / dstPts[1][2];

dstPts[2][0] = dstPts[2][0] / dstPts[2][2];
dstPts[2][1] = dstPts[2][1] / dstPts[2][2];
dstPts[2][2] = dstPts[2][2] / dstPts[2][2];

dstPts[3][0] = dstPts[3][0] / dstPts[3][2];
dstPts[3][1] = dstPts[3][1] / dstPts[3][2];
dstPts[3][2] = dstPts[3][2] / dstPts[3][2];



srcPts2 = np.array([[srcPts[0][0],srcPts[0][1]],\
                   [srcPts[1][0],srcPts[1][1]],\
                   [srcPts[2][0],srcPts[2][1]],\
                   [srcPts[3][0],srcPts[3][1]]], dtype='float32')

dstPts2 = np.array([[dstPts[0][0],dstPts[0][1]],\
                   [dstPts[1][0],dstPts[1][1]],\
                   [dstPts[2][0],dstPts[2][1]],\
                   [dstPts[3][0],dstPts[3][1]]], dtype='float32')


transMatrix = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(srcPts2, dstPts2)


dst = cv.warpPerspective(imgFile,transMatrix,(4128,2322) ,borderMode = cv.BORDER_CONSTANT,borderValue = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your code you are calculating the warp matrix by projecting four points and then use getPerspectiveTransform() to find out the transFormation matrix. This should work, but it is more complicated than necessary. If you know the roll, pitch and yaw angles, you can directly calculate the transformation matrix. Have a look at the function BirdsEyeView() in http://image2measure.net/files/calib3Dto2D.cpp . It does exactly that. 
I had to change the line 
`Mat R = RX * RY * RZ;`
to
`Mat R = RZ * RX * RY;`
in order to get it the transformation right.

*f* is the focal length in pixels.
If *rh* is the horizontal resolution of your image and *oh* the horizontal opening angle of the camera
*f = (rh/2)/tan(oh/2)* 
Choose the same value for *Distance* if you don't want to scale the image, a bigger one than *f* to enlarge it or a smaller one to shrink it.

Answer (score 0):

The code BirdsEyeView() works for me but I don't know why the Roll and Pitch angles are exchanged. When I change "alpha", the image is warped in pitch and when I change "beta" the image in warped in roll. So, I changed my rotation matrix, as can be seen below.

Also, the RY has a signal error. You can check Ry at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
I think this is the reason why Adrian changed the multiplication order from R = RX * RY * RZ to R = RZ * RX * RY.

The rotation metrix I use:

```
    Mat RX = (Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
        1,          0,           0, 0,
        0, cos(beta), -sin(beta), 0,
        0, sin(beta),  cos(beta), 0,
        0,          0,           0, 1);

    Mat RY = (Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
         cos(alpha), 0,  sin(alpha), 0,
                  0, 1,           0, 0,
        -sin(alpha), 0,  cos(alpha), 0,
                  0, 0,           0, 1);

    Mat RZ = (Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
        cos(gamma), -sin(gamma), 0, 0,
        sin(gamma),  cos(gamma), 0, 0,
        0,          0,           1, 0,
        0,          0,           0, 1);
```

Regards